Spring Boot Controller not detected despite Correct Package Structure
I have an issue where I am trying to connect the WebController with the Thymeleaf templates and get this Error when I'm trying to access the page http://localhost:8080/home:

Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/home] again

Also for @Controller and @GetMapping("/home") it says there are no usages. I have
~/../src/main/java/com/example/test/WebController.java
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class WebController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}

~/../src/main/resources/templates/home.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </body>
</html>

~/../src/main/java/com/example/test/ApiController.java
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "Greetings!";
    }
}

~/../src/main/java/com/example/test/Application.java
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

~/../src/main/java/com/example/securingweb/WebMvcConfigurer.java
package com.example.securingweb;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    }
}

~/../pom.xml
...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...

~/../src/main/resources/application.properties
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

What I tried

Package Structure: I made sure that the WebController is in the same package as the @SpringBootApplication class or a sub-package.
Component Scan: I used @ComponentScan to explicitly include the package containing the WebController.
Clean Build: I performed a clean build to eliminate any potential issues with stale artifacts.
Run the Application: I started the application to check if the /home path was working.

What I expected
I expected to access the /home path successfully and see the home.html view rendered by the WebController.
What actually happened

Instead, I received an error:


Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/home] again.


Are you getting the same result without the MvcConfig class? Does Spring know about that class? Can you try explicitly allowing/permitting the /home endpoint without authentication in your WebMvcConfigurerAdapter/SecurityFilterChain?

@dan1st Yes I get the same result without the MvcConfig class. I tried to remove the WebController as well if they are mismatching and I get 404 for /home instead. I tried moving the MvcConfig class into the same package as the Application as well so Spring should know about that class but I got the same error. I didn't have a configuration before for either WebMvcConfugrerAdapter/SecurityFilterChain. It says here under "Create an Unsecured Web Application" that it should "run the application without having to log in to anything."

Also when I added the WebSecurityConfig now with the securityFilterChain I can't access the localhost properly. It just says I have been redirected too many times.

@pseudophia can you share your code via github link because when i tested above code it worked without any issues , it would be better if you can share your code via github

@prasad thanks a lot but I solved it now! (Will post the answer of the issue)

The issue is that the MvcConfig.java & the WebController.java class are in conflict because you only need one of them. That's why this error occured

Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler
URL [/home] again

Also the stucture you had looked like this:
src/main/java
└── com
    └── example
        ├── test
        │   ├── Application.java //@SpringBootApplication
        │   ├── ApiController.java
        │   └── WebController.java
        │
        └── securingweb
            └── MvcConfig.java

But really you should have something like this:
src/main/java
└── com
    └── example
        ├── Application.java //@SpringBootApplication
        ├── test
        │   ├── ApiController.java
        │   └── WebController.java
        │
        └── securingweb
            └── MvcConfig.java

That is because Spring Boot (Application.java) needs to be in the same package or have access to the subpackages.
